# Should I make a fast operation async if the method is already async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have this code (the unimportant details are that it runs on EC2 instances in AWS, processing messages on an SQS queue).

The first statement in the method gets some data over http, the second statement saves state to a local dynamo data store.

```
public bool HandleMessage(OrderAcceptedMessage message)
{
    var order = _orderHttpClient.GetById(message.OrderId);
    _localDynamoRepo.SaveAcceptedOrder(message, order);
    return true;
}
```

The performance characteristics are that the http round trip takes 100-200 milliseconds, and the dynamo write takes around 10 milliseconds.

Both of these operations have `async` versions.  We could write it as follows:

```
public async Task<bool> HandleMessage(OrderAcceptedMessage message)
{
    var order = await _orderHttpClient.GetByIdAsync(message.OrderId);
    await _localDynamoRepo.SaveAcceptedOrderAsync(message, order);
    return true;
}
```

So the guidance is that since the first operation "could take longer than 50 milliseconds to execute" it should make use of async and await. (1)

But what about the second, fast operation? Which of these two arguments is correct:

**Do not make it async**: It does not meet the 50ms criterion and it's not worth the overhead.

**Do make it async**: The overhead has already been paid by the previous operation. There is already task-based asynchrony happening and it's worth using it.

1) http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the unimportant details are that it runs on EC2 instances in AWS, processing messages on an SQS queue

Actually, I think that's an important detail. Because this is not a UI application; it's a server application.

> the guidance is that since the first operation "could take longer than 50 milliseconds to execute"

This guidance only applies to UI applications. Thus, the 50ms guideline is meaningless here.

> Which of these two arguments is correct

Asynchrony is not about speed. It's about freeing up threads. The 50ms guideline for UI apps is all about freeing up the UI thread. On the server side, `async` is about freeing up thread pool threads.

The question is how much scalability do you want/need? If your backend is scalable, then I generally recommend `async`, because that frees up thread pool threads. This makes your web app more scalable and more able to react to changes in load more quickly. But this only gives you a benefit if your backend can scale along with your web app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, this is server app that has significant levels of load and concurrency at peak. Is there a equivalent guideline number of ms for "freeing up thread pool threads" or is it "always"?

Comment: @Anthony: If your app is under heavy load and your backend can scale, I'd just say "always". I don't know of any metrics. In this case, all `async` really does is allow you to make maximum use of your thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that in web apps the biggest cost of async is reduction of productivity. This is what we are weighing the benefits against. You need to think about how much code will be infected if you make this one method async.

The benefit is saving a thread for the duration of the call. A 200ms HTTP call is a pretty good case for async (although it's impossible to say for sure because it also depends on how often you perform the call).

The 50ms criterion is not hard number. In fact that recommendation is for realtime UI apps.

A more useful number is `latency times frequency`. That tells you how many threads are consumed in the long term average. Infrequent calls do not need to be optimized.

100 dynamo calls per second at 10ms come out at one thread blocked. This is nothing. So this probably is not a good candidate for async.

Of course if you make the first call async you can make the second one async as well at almost no incremental productivity cost because everything is infected already.

You can run the numbers yourself and decide based on that.

Answer (score 1):

This might end up in an opinionated discussion...but let's try.
*tl;dr: yes, keep it async.*

You are in a library and you don't care about the synchronisation context, so you should not capture it and change your code into:

```
var order = await _orderHttpClient.GetByIdAsync(message.OrderId).ConfigureAwait(false);
await _localDynamoRepo.SaveAcceptedOrderAsync(message, order).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Besides: after the first `await`ed call, you'll likely end up on a thread of the thread pool. So even if you use the non-async version `SaveAcceptedOrder()` it will not block. However, this is nothing you should rely on *and* you don't necessarily know the type of the async method (CPU bound or IO bound = "async by design"). If it is IO bound, there's no need to run it on a thread.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what the `ConfigureAwait` default behaviour is - what is the setting if it's not specified?

Comment: The default is `true`. See here the section "Configure Context" for more details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're making *any* remote call, make it async. Yes, DynamoDB calls are fast (except where one has a sub-par hash-key, or many gigabytes of data in a single table), but you're still making them *over the internet* (even if you're inside AWS EC2 etc), and so you should not ignore any of the [Eight Fallacies of Distributed Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing) - and especially not 1) The network is reliable or 2) Latency is zero.